# activemq: how to cause broker redelivery?

Tags: php, apache, activemq-classic, stomp

I am using activeMQ 5.10 and am trying to test the broker redelivery plugin, based on the [instructions here](http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html). I have setup the  section in my config file, but now my problem is simple: how do I actually perform a test that deliberately "breaks" a message, causing the broker to redeliver it? I have a PHP consumer (Stomp) blocking until messages arrive, and deliberately does not ACK the broker, but I don't think it's enough to indicate the message processing has "failed".
What do I need to do in order to actually see the plugin in action?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to mock a broken message. just force an error or play with the time-out (e.g. set time-out to 1 sec and force your consumer to take 3 sec to process a message - sleep for 3 secs. These are just suggestions). 
Then add to your test scrip a max number of retries, e.g. 3, from there you should look for the message being received and dropped by the receiver 3 times but the broker only send it explicitly once.
Hope this helps.... I think you've solved the most difficult part already

Answer (score 0):

For NACK (Stomp 1.2), the Stomp SEND frame must have the **persistent** flag set, otherwise it will not show up in ActiveMQ.DLQ

SO I suggest to send the messages with the persistent:true Stomp header and check if this helps.